# How I can top and buttom center a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a project and I have this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recursos/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recursos/css/menu.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <header class="centrado">
        <div class="loginregister"></div>
        <div class="espacio"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <p class="home">Home</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </header>
```

Now I'm working in the menu bar and I want to put the `<p>` home in the center of the menu div

When I put `margin-top: 10px`  to centre the home button it moves all the menu div

I have this css:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../../img/madera.jpg');
}

.centrado {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.espacio {
    height: 10px;
}

.home {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-top` on `.menu` instead of `margin-top` on `.home`.

Answer (score 0):

use position **relative** and **absolute** concept

```
.menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:absolute;//it make parent
}

.home {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:relative;// it make child now
}
```

now if you change css of home its doesn't effect all element

fore more see http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <header class="centrado">
        <div class="loginregister"></div>
        <div class="espacio"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <center>
            <p class="home">Home</p>
            </center>     
         </div>
        <hr>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

add float property  `float:left;`

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/BM7e6/1)**

```
.home {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make vertical center then simple adjust the line-height for menu to 50px that make text inside menu vertical-align middle.

```
.menu {
    height: 50px;
    line-height:50px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```